# How to convert columns to multiple boolean columns with tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr, across

I have a group of columns for each time and I want to convert it to a lot of boolean columns (one by category) with `mutate()` and `across()` like that :

```
data <- data.frame(category_t1 = c("A","B","C","C","A","B"),
                   category_t2 = c("A","C","B","B","B",NA),
                   category_t3 = c("C","C",NA,"B",NA,"A"))

data %>% mutate(across(starts_with("category"), 
                       ~case_when(.x == "A" ~ TRUE, !is.na(.x) ~ FALSE),
                       .names = "{str_replace(.col, 'category', 'A')}"),
                across(starts_with("category"), 
                       ~case_when(.x == "B" ~ TRUE, !is.na(.x) ~ FALSE),
                       .names = "{str_replace(.col, 'category', 'B')}"),
                across(starts_with("category"), 
                       ~case_when(.x == "C" ~ TRUE, !is.na(.x) ~ FALSE),
                       .names = "{str_replace(.col, 'category', 'C')}"))
```

Which makes :

```
category_t1 category_t2 category_t3  A_t1  A_t2  A_t3  B_t1  B_t2  B_t3  C_t1  C_t2
1         A           A           C  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
2         B           C           C FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
3         C           B        <NA> FALSE FALSE    NA FALSE  TRUE    NA  TRUE FALSE
4         C           B           B FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
5         A           B        <NA>  TRUE FALSE    NA FALSE  TRUE    NA FALSE FALSE
6         B        <NA>           A FALSE    NA  TRUE  TRUE    NA FALSE FALSE    NA
```

It works but I would like to know if there is a better idea because here I am doing the same code 3 times instead of one big code (and imagine if I had 10 times to repeat it...). I though I could do it with `map()` but I didn't manage to make it work.
I think there is a problem because of `.names` argument in `across()` that cannot connect with the string I use in `case_when()`.

I think maybe there is something to do in the `...` argument, like :

```
data %>% mutate(across(starts_with("category"),
                       ~case_when(.x == mod ~ TRUE, !is.na(.x) ~ FALSE),
                       mod = levels(as.factor(data$category_t1)),
                       .names = "{str_replace(.col, 'category', mod)}"))
```

But of course that doesn't work here. Do you know how to do that ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Don't know bout tidyverse, I would simply do `for (i in LETTERS[1:3]) data[paste0(i, "_t", 1:3)] <- data == i`

Comment: Love that one @DavidArenburg!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `table` in `across`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
data %>%
   mutate(across(everything(), ~ as.data.frame.matrix(table(row_number(), .x) * 
     NA^(is.na(.x)) > 0),
    .names = "{str_remove(.col, 'category_')}")) %>% 
  unpack(where(is.data.frame), names_sep = ".")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 12
  category_t1 category_t2 category_t3 t1.A  t1.B  t1.C  t2.A  t2.B  t2.C  t3.A  t3.B  t3.C 
  <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
1 A           A           C           TRUE  FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE 
2 B           C           C           FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE TRUE 
3 C           B           <NA>        FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE TRUE  FALSE NA    NA    NA   
4 C           B           B           FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE
5 A           B           <NA>        TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE NA    NA    NA   
6 B           <NA>        A           FALSE TRUE  FALSE NA    NA    NA    TRUE  FALSE FALSE
```

---

Or use `model.matrix` from `base R`

```
data1 <- replace(data, is.na(data), "NA")
lvls <- lapply(data1, \(x) levels(factor(x, levels = c("NA", "A", "B", "C"))))
m1 <- model.matrix(~ 0 + ., data = data1, xlev = lvls)

out <- cbind(data, m1[, -grep("NA", colnames(m1))] > 0)
```

-output

```
out
category_t1 category_t2 category_t3 category_t1A category_t1B category_t1C category_t2A category_t2B category_t2C category_t3A category_t3B category_t3C
1           A           A           C         TRUE        FALSE        FALSE         TRUE        FALSE        FALSE        FALSE        FALSE         TRUE
2           B           C           C        FALSE         TRUE        FALSE        FALSE        FALSE         TRUE        FALSE        FALSE         TRUE
3           C           B        <NA>        FALSE        FALSE         TRUE        FALSE         TRUE        FALSE        FALSE        FALSE        FALSE
4           C           B           B        FALSE        FALSE         TRUE        FALSE         TRUE        FALSE        FALSE         TRUE        FALSE
5           A           B        <NA>         TRUE        FALSE        FALSE        FALSE         TRUE        FALSE        FALSE        FALSE        FALSE
6           B        <NA>           A        FALSE         TRUE        FALSE        FALSE        FALSE        FALSE         TRUE        FALSE        FALSE
> colnames(out)
 [1] "category_t1"  "category_t2"  "category_t3" 
 [4] "category_t1A" "category_t1B" "category_t1C"
 [7] "category_t2A" "category_t2B" "category_t2C"
 [10] "category_t3A"
[11] "category_t3B" "category_t3C"
```

---

Or another option with `table`

```
cbind(data, do.call(cbind.data.frame,
  lapply(data, \(x) (table(seq_along(x), x)* NA^is.na(x)) > 0)))
```

-output

```
category_t1 category_t2 category_t3 category_t1.A category_t1.B category_t1.C category_t2.A category_t2.B category_t2.C category_t3.A category_t3.B
1           A           A           C          TRUE         FALSE         FALSE          TRUE         FALSE         FALSE         FALSE         FALSE
2           B           C           C         FALSE          TRUE         FALSE         FALSE         FALSE          TRUE         FALSE         FALSE
3           C           B        <NA>         FALSE         FALSE          TRUE         FALSE          TRUE         FALSE            NA            NA
4           C           B           B         FALSE         FALSE          TRUE         FALSE          TRUE         FALSE         FALSE          TRUE
5           A           B        <NA>          TRUE         FALSE         FALSE         FALSE          TRUE         FALSE            NA            NA
6           B        <NA>           A         FALSE          TRUE         FALSE            NA            NA            NA          TRUE         FALSE
  category_t3.C
1          TRUE
2          TRUE
3            NA
4         FALSE
5            NA
6         FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a `tidyverse` option (although pipe-compatible), it is very easily doable with package `fastDummies`:

```r
fastDummies::dummy_cols(data, ignore_na = TRUE)
```

```r
  category_t1 category_t2 category_t3 category_t1_A category_t1_B category_t1_C category_t2_A category_t2_B category_t2_C category_t3_A category_t3_B category_t3_C
1           A           A           C             1             0             0             1             0             0             0             0             1
2           B           C           C             0             1             0             0             0             1             0             0             1
3           C           B        <NA>             0             0             1             0             1             0            NA            NA            NA
4           C           B           B             0             0             1             0             1             0             0             1             0
5           A           B        <NA>             1             0             0             0             1             0            NA            NA            NA
6           B        <NA>           A             0             1             0            NA            NA            NA             1             0             0
```

Answer (score 1):

`purrr`'s `map_dfc` could match well with your current approach:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

bind_cols(data, 
          map_dfc(LETTERS[1:3], \(letter) { mutate(data,
                                                   across(starts_with("category"), 
                                                          ~ case_when(.x == letter ~ TRUE, !is.na(.x) ~ FALSE),
                                                   .names = paste0("{str_replace(.col, 'category', '", letter, "')}")),
                                                   .keep = "none") }
                  )
          )
```

Or skip the `bind_cols` and use `.keep = ifelse(letter == "A", "all", "none")`.

Output:

```r
  category_t1 category_t2 category_t3  A_t1  A_t2  A_t3  B_t1  B_t2  B_t3  C_t1  C_t2  C_t3
1           A           A           C  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
2           B           C           C FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
3           C           B        <NA> FALSE FALSE    NA FALSE  TRUE    NA  TRUE FALSE    NA
4           C           B           B FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
5           A           B        <NA>  TRUE FALSE    NA FALSE  TRUE    NA FALSE FALSE    NA
6           B        <NA>           A FALSE    NA  TRUE  TRUE    NA FALSE FALSE    NA FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

A `base` solution with nested `lapply()`:

```r
cbind(data, lapply(data, \(x) {
  lev <- levels(factor(x))
  sapply(setNames(lev, lev), \(y) x == y)
}))

  category_t1 category_t2 category_t3 category_t1.A category_t1.B category_t1.C category_t2.A category_t2.B category_t2.C category_t3.A category_t3.B category_t3.C
1           A           A           C          TRUE         FALSE         FALSE          TRUE         FALSE         FALSE         FALSE         FALSE          TRUE
2           B           C           C         FALSE          TRUE         FALSE         FALSE         FALSE          TRUE         FALSE         FALSE          TRUE
3           C           B        <NA>         FALSE         FALSE          TRUE         FALSE          TRUE         FALSE            NA            NA            NA
4           C           B           B         FALSE         FALSE          TRUE         FALSE          TRUE         FALSE         FALSE          TRUE         FALSE
5           A           B        <NA>          TRUE         FALSE         FALSE         FALSE          TRUE         FALSE            NA            NA            NA
6           B        <NA>           A         FALSE          TRUE         FALSE            NA            NA            NA          TRUE         FALSE         FALSE
```